# Can we use 125VAC 20A switch in place of 12VDC 20A switch?

Tags: switches, power-electronics, power-engineering, electrical

Can we use 125VAC 20A switch in place of 12VDC 20A switch?
I have searched my local market and found 125VAC 20A switch. Can i use this AC switch in place of 12V 20A switch as it is not available in market?

Comment: Not if it doesn't say it can also switch DC at that current. There's a world of difference to switches between a voltage that stays on or one that crosses 0V many times a second.

Comment: I generally use a rule that I can derate a VAC-rated switch to a DC-rated switch by dividing by 10. This isn't the correct way to do it, but it's close as a rule. AC extinguishes switching arcs when it zero-crosses. But DC doesn't have a zero-cross, so the arc is drawn out for a while longer when the switch opens. So DC can be much harder on a switch than AC. Which is a reason why to derate.

Comment: http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/electricalratings.pdf

Comment: Watch this video to get a visual demonstration of the arc issues with DC. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY

Answer (score 1):

With the exact same 20A current rating? Almost definitely not.

The right answer is always going to depend heavily on the switch in question. In industrial applications I have seen big, heavy switches that actually had the same listed rating for AC and DC applications. From a design standpoint, that is accomplished by designing a switch that can withstand extinguishing a DC arc, *and* be sufficiently insulated to handle AC voltages. This is a highly unusual case, as it means the switch is significantly more expensive than it needed to be for either case.

Switches frequently have both AC and DC ratings, but in the more common case, the DC current rating will be significantly lower than the AC one. DC arcs take longer to extinguish and cause more wear on the contacts. In a 20 amp application, I expect that an AC switch with the same rating would fail quickly, and badly.